# SQL to LINQ - Left Join Before Inner Join

Tags: c#, linq, join, sql-to-linq-conversion

So I have a SQL query that I would like to convert to LINQ.

Here is said query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableA ta
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableB tb
    ON tb.ShipId = ta.ShipId
    INNER JOIN DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableC tc
    ON tc.PostageId= tb.PostageId
WHERE tc.PostageCode = 'Package'
      AND ta.MailId = 'Specification'
```

The problem I am struggling with is I cannot seem to figure out how to do a left join in LINQ before an inner join, since doing a left join in LINQ is not as clear to me at least.

I have found numerous examples of a LINQ inner join and then a left join, but not left join and then inner join.

If it helps, here is the LINQ query I have been playing around with:

```
var query = from m in tableA
join s in tableB on m.ShipId equals s.ShipId into queryDetails
from qd in queryDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
join p in tableC on qd.PostageId equals p.PostageId
where m.MailId == "Specification" && p.PostageCode == "Package"
select m.MailId;
```

I have tried this a few different ways but I keep getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on qd.PostageId.

LINQ is very new to me and I love learning it, so any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I think so! I have yet to implement it yet because I'm away from my laptop, but upon reading through the answers make sense. I will be sure to test tomorrow and select the best answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var query = from m in tableA
join s in tableB on m.ShipId equals s.ShipId
join p in tableC on s.PostageId equals p.PostageId
where m.MailId == "Specification" && p.PostageCode == "Package"
select m.MailId;
```

Your query uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it doesn't need it.

It will, in practice, function as an `INNER JOIN` due to your `tc.PostageCode = 'Package'` clause. *If you compare to a column value in a table in a `WHERE` clause (and there are no `OR` clauses and you aren't comparing to `NULL`) then effectively **all** joins to get to that table will be treated as `INNER`).*

That clause will **never** be true if `TableB` is `null` (which is why you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` vs `INNER JOIN`) - so you should just use an `INNER JOIN` to make the problem simpler.

Comment: I don't see how `tc.PostageCode` affects the `OUTER JOIN` of `TableB`, though your conclusion is correct. Also, if you do `into queryDetails` you can't reference `s` after that (it won't compile).

Comment: If you removed the `WHERE` clause in the SQL, the `JOIN` between `TableA` and `TableB` is still _effectively_ an `INNER JOIN` because there is an `INNER JOIN` between `TableB` and `TableC` - the `WHERE` clause has nothing to do with it.

Comment: That is true @NetMage, and certainly a valid way to look at it. Here is another way. Let's say the query was `SELECT *
FROM DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableA ta
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableB tb
    ON tb.ShipId = ta.ShipId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DatabaseA.SchemaA.TableC tc
    ON tc.PostageId= tb.PostageId
WHERE tc.PostageCode = 'Package'
      AND ta.MailId = 'Specification'` instead. In that case, both `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s are effectively INNER due to the WHERE clause. That is what I was trying to teach the OP.

Comment: That is true, but not the query :)

Answer (score 2):

From my [SQL conversion recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49245786/2557128):

1. `JOIN` conditions that aren't all equality tests with `AND` must be handled using `where` clauses outside the join, or with cross product (`from` ... `from` ...) and then `where`
2. `JOIN` conditions that are multiple `AND`ed equality tests between the two tables should be translated into anonymous objects
3. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another from `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

The order of `JOIN` clauses doesn't change how you translate them:

```
var ans = from ta in TableA
          join tb in TableB on ta.ShipId equals tb.ShipId into tbj
          from tb in tbj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join tc in TableC on tb.PostageId equals tc.PostageId
          where tc.PostageCode == "Package" && ta.MailId == "Specification"
          select new { ta, tb, tc };
```

However, because the `LEFT JOIN` is executed before the `INNER JOIN` and then the `NULL` `PostageId`s in `TableB` for unmatched rows will never match any row in `TableC`, it becomes equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` as well, which translates as:

```
var ans2 = from ta in tableA
           join tb in tableB on ta.ShipId equals tb.ShipId
           join tc in tableC on tb.PostageId equals tc.PostageId
           where tc.PostageCode == "Package" && ta.MailId == "Specification"
           select new { ta, tb, tc };
```